# Eliminate duplication in similar fake data access classes

Tags: c#

Can I combine this two classes and have one fake db class?

```
public class FakeDb : Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    public const string Table1 = "Table1";

    public void AddToTable(string tableName, string line)
    {
        if(!ContainsKey(tableName))
            Add(tableName, new List<string>());

        List<string> rows = GetTableData(tableName);
        rows.Add(line);
    }

    internal List<string> GetTableData(string tableName)
    {
        return this[tableName];
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FakeComplexDb : Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>>
{
    public void AddToTable(string tableName, Dictionary<string, List<string>> line)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(tableName))
            Add(tableName, new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>());

        List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> rows = GetTableData(tableName);
        rows.Add(line);
    }

    internal List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetTableData(string tableName)
    {
        return this[tableName];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use generics:

```
public class FakeDb<TList> : Dictionary<string, List<TList>>
{
    public const string Table1 = "Table1";

    public void AddToTable(string tableName, TList line)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(tableName))
        {
            Add(tableName, new List<TList>());
        }

        List<TList> rows = GetTableData(tableName);
        rows.Add(line);
    }

    private List<TList> GetTableData(string tableName)
    {
        return this[tableName];
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
var simpleDB = new FakeDb<string>();
var complexDb = new FakeDb<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```